# Google Cloud Platform VPS Firewall Rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-firewall

thanks for read my post. I am a newcomer.
Today i was working with Google Cloud VPS and I discovery how to able ports in the google firewall rules, so I put rules for port 7171 and 7172 but do not work yet. Looks blocked.

I can do something more to enable por 7171 and 7172 on Google Cloud Platform or theres a imposed restriction by google? Ah, I already released the ports on the windows firewall.

Windows server 2008

Thank you
Andre

PRINT OF ALL GOOGLE FIREWALL RULES

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you would have to do followings:

In GCP:

1) Create a firewall rule to allowing ingress for ports 7171 and 7172 for specific source or any source.
2) You can create this firewall rules for all the VM's in the network or with tags to apply it for particular VM or VMs.

At this point, ingress traffic will be allowed by Google Cloud Platform (GCP) to VM(s) as per source and ports specified in the firewall rule. Ingress traffic should reach backend VM(s), in case still blocking check Windows 2008 firewall to make sure it is allowing ports 7171 and 7172.

In Windows 2008:

Make sure port is not blocking, and service is listening on this port, you could use following command for this:
netstat -aon  or to check 7171 port
netstat -aon | findstr 7171

This will provide you details information like protocol, Local address, foreign address, connection state and Process ID, more details can be found in this serverfault [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/26564/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-blocked-on-a-windows-machine).

You have mentioned you have already opened the ports in windows, however, if you like you could check and verify your configuration following this internet [document](https://dbatricksworld.com/how-to-open-firewall-ports-on-windows-server-2008-r2/).